# MVC 4 @Html.DropDownListFor() not passing model values to dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am new to MVC and trying a test application to get my feet wet.  Part of this application is to generate a form with a drop down box. I use the

@Html.DropDownListFor() to generate this, and on the create form the drop down works fine.  But when I go to the edit form the model value is not passing to the drop down.

SelectList Item

```
 public static string[] OnOffList()
    {
        var ret = new string[] { "On", "Off" };
        return ret;
    }
```

Form code

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ServiceCondition, new SelectList(OnOffDropDownHelper.OnOffList()))
```

For this instance assume that model.ServiceCondition = "Off".

For some reason whenever I call this form the dropdown value is always "On", it seems to be completely ignoring the model value.

I have also tried this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ServiceCondition, new SelectList(OnOffDropDownHelper.OnOffList(), "Off"))
```

to mandate the "Off" value, but it is still coming up as "On" as the selected value in the drop down.

I would like to reiterate, I do know that the model value is "Off", and I created an identical "Create" form using the same @Html.DropDownListFor() and it was able to pass the value to the model just fine.

Like I said, I am new to MVC so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be a rookie mistake on my part.

Who ever designed the databese had the field ServiceCondition as nchar(8) leaving white space at the end of the "on     ", "Off    " values.

A .Trim() in the field in question fixed the issue.

Thanks a ton for the help.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to set the `IsSelected` property. This always works for me:

First, just put a property in your model to tidy up the View code:

```
public List<SelectListItem> OnOffDDL
{
    get
    {
        return OnOffDropDownHelper.OnOffList()
            .Select(s => new SelectListItem
                         {
                             Text = s,
                             Value = s,
                             Selected = ServiceCondition == s
                         })
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Then do:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ServiceCondition, model.OnOffDDL)
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be a little overkill, but is helpful if your model could have different options based on the model itself (even though for now it is just On and Off). Like in the future if certain items could have a "Standby" mode, etc, where you would be getting the actual options from a database for that particular item.

Use a SelectList for the source, so your Model could have:

```
public List<SelectListItem> OnOffList{ get; set; }
```

Then populating the Model in your controller like:

```
model.OnOffList.Add(new SelectListItem()
{
    Text = "On",
    Value = "On"
});
```

...etc.

Then you can set the selected item like:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ServiceCondition, new SelectList(Model.OnOffList(), "Value", "Text", Model.ServiceCondition))
```